# getting wrong NSDate and Formate Using NSDateFormatter (datefromString)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsnotificationcenter

- Hi, I am using the below code in my project.
- I am posting the notification from one view to another view. passing
  string(date) as parameter of Nsnotifiationcenter,but i am not able to
  covert passed date into original date format I require.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the problem? Your code is working perfectly. When you log or print the `NSDate` object, it will log the date in the full format you see using the UTC timezone. The value of `date` is correct.

Comment: IST (India) has a +5,5... That's a Time Zone Issue.

Comment: @rmaddy ya but i want a date exactly how i am passing.You can see the date is decremented by one day.

Comment: @Rushabh not working. still getting the same problem

Comment: @utkalpatel It is working. Read what I said again. It's simply a display issue. If you want to format the `NSDate` a specific way then use an `NSDataFormatter` to convert it to a string with the desired format. Or simply use the string you started with.

Comment: @Rushabh There is no need to deal with the timezone. That's not the problem (there is no problem).